# Check proof that $f_n(x)=x/n$ does not converge uniformly.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, solution-verification, uniform-convergence, sequence-of-function

Let $(f_n: \mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ be the sequence of functions defined by

$$f_n(x)=\frac{x}{n}$$
for every $n\in\mathbb N$ and $x\in\mathbb R$. I would like to show $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ does not converge uniformly on $\mathbb R$.

My attempt:

Let us suppose $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ converges uniformly to $f: \mathbb R\longrightarrow \mathbb R$. In particular, $f_n(x)\to f(x)$ for every $x\in \mathbb R$ when $n\to \infty$. But:

$$0=\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{x}{n}=\lim_{n\to \infty} f_n(x)=f(x)$$

for every $x\in\mathbb R$ and, therefore, $f=0$. Next, since $f_n\to f$ uniformly, given $\varepsilon=1$ there exists $n_0\in\mathbb N$ such that:

$$\forall n\geq n_0 \Rightarrow \frac{|x|}{n}=|f_n(x)|<1$$
for every $x\in\mathbb R$. But this is impossible since taking $n=n_0$ and $x=n_0+1$ we get

$$|f_n(x)|=\frac{|x|}{n}=\frac{n_0+1}{n_0}=1+\frac{1}{n_0}>1.$$

Is my proof correct? Is it standard or there is a more elegant way of writing?

Thanks.

Comment: Your idea is totally correct. It may be slightly more elegant to prove it directly, as in: instead of supposing it converges uniformly and arriving at a contradiction, just use the definition to prove it does not converge uniformly. The proof is basically the same. You're still going to have $\epsilon=1$, $x=n+1$, etc.

Comment: Also, I find it odd your use of the word "But" after the supposition. It makes me think the "but" is intended on detailing a contradiction. However, you are really just providing the reader with an explanation of what $f(x)$ is. I would use softer language, like "note that the limiting function $f(x)$ must equal zero" or something.

Comment: @zugzug right, direct proofs are always more elegant. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: @zugzug as to the language I can justify myself. I am not a native english speaker, I'm brasilian, so my written expression may be a bit sloppy.

Comment: I'm a native speaker and yet my english is still terrible. I didn't mean to cut you up.